# Flutter cannot connect to emulator in VSCode. Waiting for a connection from Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I can see the device list on VSCode in Windows.
And I can select any one.
And the emulator is opening.
But I can see a single message. "Waiting for a connection from Flutter.."
Application does not open.
It doesn't get any errors either. Waiting like this.

[image]

Comment: what version of flutter are you using?\

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that your API level you're running your device on is the
   same as what you have installed on Android Studio.

   1.1 Click on the SDK Manager button around the top right corner of AS (The icon is a box with a down arrow next to it).

   1.2 Choose the same API level as your device, (When I didn't do this I had a partial install and it took some time to compile), then
   click apply and wait for it to install.
2. We're going to run the project to our avd or mobile device from the directory of ourproject.

   2.1 Open up the Command Prompt (preferably as Admin), and chage the directoy to where your project is, the command should look something
   like this:

   > cd Documents/flutterprojects/yourflutterproject.

   2.2 Finally type the command flutter run.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Emulator by holding the power Button and Selecting restart and then try again.
if that failed to work, simply restart your computer.

Comment: I followed both of your recommendations. But nothing changed.

Comment: try running the emulator from android studio and then try and see if the emulator is picked up by flutter. or run Flutter run directly on console.